# Apache/Tomcat site nesting

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, servlets

I have two standalone sites in tomcat webapps folder

- `$TOMCAT_HOME/siteA` which is registered in DNS as *siteA.example.com* and
- `$TOMCAT_HOME/siteB` which is NOT registered in DNS

Both sites are written in Java/Servlets.

Is there a way to setup apache/tomcat/mod-rewrite to call siteB like so?

```
siteA.example.com/siteB
```

Does this level of nesting make sense?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Give `siteA` a context path of `/` and give `siteB` a context path of `/siteB`, then it should just work.